# how solve Android SDK contains licenses only

Tags: flutter

] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
! Android SDK contains licenses only.
Your first build of an Android application will take longer than usual, while gradle downloads the missing
components. This functionality will only work if the licenses in the licenses folder in ANDROID_HOME are valid.
If the Android SDK has been installed to another location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

```
  Certain features, such as `flutter emulators` and `flutter devices`, will not work without the currently missing
  SDK components.
```

Comment: Did you try flutter doctor command

Comment: please edit the answer to include `flutter doctor -v` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android component not found. please update PATH.
Use flutter documentaion [Install](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

And you facing andorid licence problem then run

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```